# Getting multiple address for a mail in .pst files

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, interop, office-interop

I have successfully read the .pst files thorough C#.

The issue is if a mail has multiple recipient (i.e. sender email address) then I am not able to get those multiple address. with the code

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            outlookNs.AddStore(@"D:\pst\Test.pst");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
            List<MailItem> lstMails = emailFolder.Items.OfType<MailItem>().Where(x=>x.SenderEmailAddress.Contains("hari")).Select(x=>x).ToList();
            foreach (Object obj in emailFolder.Items)
            {
               if(obj is MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem item = (MailItem)obj;
                    Console.WriteLine(item.SenderEmailAddress + " " + item.Subject + "\n" + item.Body);
                }
            }
```

item.SenderEmailAddress is returning a very strange address for multiple recipient, also if i have made any group of people and send mail to them then also.

So any one can guide how to read those multiple address and also the name of the group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    outlookNs.AddStore(@"D:\pst\Test.pst");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    List<MailItem> lstMails = emailFolder.Items.OfType<MailItem>().Where(x=>x.SenderEmailAddress.Contains("hari")).Select(x=>x).ToList();
    foreach (Object obj in emailFolder.Items)
    {
       if(obj is MailItem)
        {
            MailItem item = (MailItem)obj;
           String user=String.Empty;
            foreach (Object obj1 in ((dynamic)item).Recipients)
            {
                user += ((dynamic)obj1).Name + ";";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(user + " " + item.Subject + "\n" + item.Body);
        }
    }
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, do not use LINQ with Outlook. It might look cool in your code, but you need to realize that all the processing is done on the client side, it is not any different from explicitly looping through all items in the folder.
Use Items.Restrict or Find/FindNext - the search will be performed by the store provider.